# How convert input String to Integer groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a String and I need to sum, but I don't know how!

How I can convert String Input like this:

```
01:20
```

to Integer for use in sum of hour and minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got your string defined in variable:

```
String timeStr = '01:00'
```

The shortest way I can think of would look like:

```
timeStr[0..1].toInteger()
```

Just to clarify, the above line is equivalent of:

```
timeStr.substring(0, 2).toInteger()
```

Please note the difference between specifying 'to' index.
With Groovy range it's inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse that into a Date using:

```
Date.parse( 'HH:mm', '01:00' )
```

If you need something to add on to a `Date` at a later time, you can do:

```
import groovy.time.*

String time = '01:00'

def duration = use( TimeCategory ) {
    Date.parse( 'HH:mm', time ) - Date.parse( 'HH:mm', '00:00' )
}
```

Then, later on:

```
use( TimeCategory ) {
    println new Date() + duration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def hours = Date.parse("HH:mm", str).getHours();
```

Comment: You're right, but why not use shorter _property notation_ and String type instead of GString like:`int hours = Date.parse('HH:mm', str).hours`

Comment: @topr `"HH:mm"` _is_ a String

Comment: @tim_yates Well technically that's true until there would be an `${expression}` used between the quotation marks. But why use double quotes where it's not necessary? Of course it is the matter of coding convention among a given project. I find cleaner to not use double quotes when no need. For example [CodeNarc static analysis tool has rule](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rules-unnecessary.html#UnnecessaryGString) which would be violate on such code.

Comment: Yeah, but it is a String type, not a GString type as you say in your comment.

Comment: mainly because I'm a java developer with a little groovy experience, and I go for the java syntax by default (which is not always good :) )